# Spring and React Native - push notifications?

Tags: spring, react-native, push-notification, spring-websocket

I am developing a web application with a Spring Backend and a React Native Frontend.
In my app, there are two types of users : *students* and *teachers*. Currently, the students can ask a question to the teacher, that question is saved in the database and later on the teacher will answer the question.

I want to make it so that when the teacher has answered a question, the student receives a little pop-up notification of his/her phone.
Unfortunately, I have no experience with push notifications or reactive programming in general.

I would like to ask you **what libraries/frameworks/tools I should use to program something like this**. After a little searching online, for the Spring app I am thinking of using Spring WebSocket and I should somehow subscribe to it from the React Native app. Am I on the right track ? How should I go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use firebase with push notification
Since google push message is free for all, u can send n-number of messages by server also

U can write spring code when you need to send the push notification and I can't help in spring code. Either u should send the token or topics which is register by mobile application.

In React-Native application you follow the official docs, click on the [link](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage). This firebase push notification work in background and for foreground you need to learn and work on [react-native push notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification). If you create the foreground notification don't forget to create the channel https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#channel-management-android.

Hope I have answered your question

If you get any doubt, comment below